# Admob banner ad best practices

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have 3 viewcontroller embedded in a tabbarcontroller,and currently i am using a separate banner ad in each viewcontroller,my question is which is better one banner add in appdelegate or each one in a viewcontroller’s viewdidload
(Note: using a uiview and defining it as Gadbanneradd class)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better in window instead of spreading it every where

In `AppDelegate` use

```
 self.window?.addSubview(adBanner)
```

//

From any VC use

```
let win = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window
win?.addSubiew(adBanner)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of solutions possible. One direction I'd probably look at would be to have a top level view controller which has two child view controllers. One being a tab bar controller and the other your ad view controller.

The advantage of this is that the top level view controller's view can then layout two embedded view controller views in any layout it wants. Plus, it can handle the showing and hiding of ads as you need. In addition it also means that the tab view controller doesn't know or need to know anything at all about the ads. It's not even aware they are on screen.